# find with -prune leaves pruned directory names

Tags: find, tcsh

I constructed the following find command:

```
find ./ \( -path "*work*" -o -path "*ncvlog_lib*" \) -prune -o -type f -not
-name "*.wlf" -not -name "*.vcd" -not -name "*.sim" -not -name "*vcs*"
```

The command is invoked in a single line. I broke the line here for readability.

The only trouble is that it prints the pruned directory names, despite providing the -type f argument. Sample output:

```
./cdl2verilog_files/test_synth/work
./cdl2verilog_files/test_synth/some_file1.txt
./cdl2verilog_files/test_synth/something_else.txt
./cdl2verilog_files/test_synth/another_file.v
```

`work` is a directory. Its contents are not included in the output, so the prune works as needed. However, the directory itself is printed out. I can't seem to find a solution for this. Any thoughts?

I am using tcsh by the way.

Comment: FYI you can end a line with a backslash `\ ` to continue it onto the next line.  This works in bourne-type shells like sh, bash, ksh etc and in csh/tcsh.  BTW, since you mentioned tcsh I am contractually obliged to mention [csh considered harmful](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/csh) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-prune` excludes the directory's contents, but not the directory itself. This happens if `-prune` is the only **action** in a `find` command.  If there were any other action (e.g. `-exec` or `-print`), it would not output the pruned directory names.  So you just have to add an explicit `-print` in the end of your `find` command. For example:

```
find ./ \( -path "*work*" -o -path "*ncvlog_lib*" \) -prune -o -type f  \
  -not -name "*.wlf" -not -name "*.vcd" -not -name "*.sim" -not -name "*vcs*" \
  -print
```

BTW, you can shorten/simplify your `find` command by using a single `-regex` predicate rather than multiple `-name` predicates.  e.g.

```
find ./ \( -path "*work*" -o -path "*ncvlog_lib*" \) -prune -o -type f \
  -regextype awk -not -regex '.*\.(wlf|vcd|sim)$|.*vcs.*' -print
```

This produces output identical to that of the first version above.

Comment: It took me a min to realize _why_ this is, as in the man page, it's sort of a double negative. 

`find` runs `-print` on _every file_ for which the *full expression* is true _unless_ the expression contains an action _other than_ `-prune` or `-quit`. i.e., `find` defaults to `-print` unless *somewhere* you tell it to do something else.

For something like `-path "work/*" -prune -o -type f`, the only action in the expression is `-prune`, and since the point of `-prune -o` is to short-circuit the expression to true,   `find` runs `-print` on those matches, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case

```
-prune -o -type f
```

is ambigus : `-o` meaning "or", when `find` finds a directory, the `-prune` is true, so `-type f` is not evaluated